# Delphi xe3 Access Violation on database read - debugger goes through

Tags: sql, delphi, debugging, access-violation, delphi-xe3

So, I ran into this weird situation I can't seem to find solution by any way...
I get Access Violation error, which only occurs on normal run, but not in the debugger, and only when reading more than specific amount of data from database.

I set a timer on main form, so that it starts the procedure a second after the form is displayed (just in case if too early query would make trouble; the prime code was with OnCreate event...);

This is the code:

```
procedure TStartup1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var ch, val: integer;
begin
  AdoQueryOutput2.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM LastOutput_Uni1 WHERE ID > 430';
    with AdoQueryOutput2 do
      begin
      open;
        while not eof do
          begin
            ch:=FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
            val:=FieldByName('LastValue').AsInteger;
            SendDriver.SetDataValue(ch, val);
            next;
          end;
        close;
      end;
      Timer1.Enabled:=False;
end;
```

Now, with this query, OR if I completely remove the "WHERE ID > 430" criteria, I get the AV error:

```
Access violation at address 005361FB in module Bitstack.exe. Read of address 00000074;
```

However, if I raise the criteria id to 440, the AV does NOT appear; also, if I add the criteria to be "WHERE ID > 430 AND ID < 480" for example, it does not raise AV error.
The database table has 512 entries, so all ID records are 512, each has representative data in a field "LastOutput", which is then sent to SendDriver unit's SetDataValue procedure, as you can see in the code;
Both data types are integer;

The weird thing is, that if I set breakpoints and run in the debug mode, and then go through the breakpoints continuing with F9 by hand, it runs from 1 to 150 without any problem (when no "WHERE" criteria is set), but if I run it in normal mode, the AV error raises the same second the app opens.

Any ideas what is causing this? If there's any additional info required, which I forgot to mention, please notify me.
Thank you!

---

UPDATE #3:

Here is procedure  executed:

```
procedure SendDriver.SetDataValue (Channel: LongInt; Data: LongInt);
begin
 Output.Led[Channel-1].Caption:=AddLeadingZeroes(Data, 3);
end
```

This does the trick in the Output form, which has array of labels,,  so that channel corresponding label changes caption to value.;

So far I've come to the point, where it all works ok if the query has criteria "WHERE ID <> 74".
Now, why is this 74 so important, I have no idea.
Tried to put a SendDriver.SetDataValue(74, 0) on button event, and it raises AV error as well.

Anyone knows why would this 74 be so important?

Comment: Haven't read your question through, but definitely stop that timer as the first thing in your method.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? Apparently you are accessing a `nil` object reference. Which object reference is `nil`? Aside: what is the point of that `next`? Are you hoping that the next iteration will start sooner?

Comment: That then won't start the query at all, so no AV error will be raised.
If you think that the timer loop is the problem: I do stop the timer as it's last "OnTimer" event, if you look at the last row of a code...

Comment: @David, the debugger does nothing but goes through breakpoints normally. It does the code execution normally. As said, I can't see the error because AV is only raised if run normally, not via debugger. But since the data limit kinda eliminates the AV, I can't imagine why would there be access try to nil object only when more than x amount is read...
As for the next: Isn't that the necessary event, when reading through the whole table with "while not EOF"...???
Last time I got my app to stop responding was exactly because it was set to an endless loop - because I forgot to add "next" there. :O

Comment: It's clearly an access of a nil pointer. It's reading an offset of $74 from `nil`. You need to do some debugging. Find out which object ref is `nil`. Myself, I always have madExcept in my processes and it gives lovely stack traces in such events.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, please check update to a question.
+, can you explain what you meant with why I put a "next" in there, for me to understand it better? Thanks.

Comment: That `Next` is correct there.

Comment: Well, you need to find the nil object reference. That's for you to do. As for the `next`, what do you think it does? How do you think the loop behaves if you remove the `next`?

Comment: @TLama In what sense is it correct? What does it add?

Comment: The timer should not matter since you hopefully are not pumping the queue. That said, you might as well disable the timer as the first act to the function.

Comment: @David, there is a `while` loop which ends when you reach `Eof`. And without that `Next` you will stay on the first record.

Comment: @TLama OK, I was caught out by the syntax highlighter. It styles `next` as a keyword and I thought that was the Pascal keyword for *move to next iteration of loop*. But I guess it is the `next` method of the object in the `with`. Right?

Comment: @StillBeginnerMarc One thing you should do is get rid of the `with` statement. It's not too late for you to learn that `with` is evil.

Comment: @David, yup, it is so.

Comment: @StillBeginnerMarc Looking at the update, how can we help? There are labels and UI? Not in what we can see. I suggest you do some debugging. We can tell you how, but you need to do it. Or give us an SSCCE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's exactly what there's that next, yes. As you asked, what I think it does - it moves me to the next record so that I don't stay on the first and loop, and then as I mentioned before - end up in not responding app.
MartynA - The timer is set to be 1, now 5 seconds. Even if it's enabled, it executes AFTER that time, so this shouldn't be a problem if it's enabled from the start.
David - I thought it's good to use that "with" in there... why is it so "evil"..?

Comment: @StillBeginnerMarc I was caught out by the syntax highlighter. I understand now. Sorry. Stop using `with` though!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see.
Hm, what's with the with? I'd really love to know why it's bad.
What would SSCCE stand for...? :/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I will update the question with the complete procedure tree, simplified, so that you'll see exactly as it is.

Comment: @StillBeginnerMarc Because it widens scope. And so it's harder for you to know what object a method is being called on. Suppose that `TStartup1` has a method named `next`. Now it is hidden by the `with`. Or you have a local variable named `next`. Again, hidden by the `with`. This is discussed again and again and surely a websearch will yield more.

Comment: Oh, ok, now I see what you mean.
Well, on my luck, this can't happen as I always use procedures and variables with custom names and numbers by it, exactly because I fear that I'll get lost because there are lots of forms and global variables on them, and each form uses each one so... yeah. :) Worth of knowing this about "with" though, thanks...

The question has been updated again. Hint: please don't get mad about me using 512 timers on a form. I'm just about to update it so it will only use one. This seemed to be the only solution back then when I wrote it. :D

Comment: @StillBeginnerMarc:  So now you're telling us that there is more than one form involved?  AVs are often caused by object lifetime issues of the sort that arise where you have multiple forms/data modules involved.  and, in the original version of your q, how were readers supposed to know whether SendDriver is owned by your form (if it is).  You'd do far better to follow what DavidH suggests and try and reproduce your problem in an SSCCE that you could post in toto, so readers don't have to guess which objects are being declared where, and what's going on in code they can't see.

Comment: @MartynA You're correct. I did tell only part of the whole story, but that's because I haven't seen that the trouble is in the other form in the first place - read update 1, I saw that only after tried to debug with no breakpoints.

I'm copying there parts of code in new project to reproduce the problem and try to isolate it... Thanks for hints though!

Comment: Makes no bloody sense.
Removed the coloring event, completely disabled the whole timer array, so basically all I have is array of labels, and database query, which then reads and sets caption of labels based on database read.
When reading with criteria WHERE ID > 74 or more (75, 76 or any higher number), WORKS, if I go on 73 or lower, I get different AV error, when trying to show the form with the labels; It breaks in Vcl.Forms at procedure TCustomForm.SetVisible(Value: Boolean);
There is NO difference in labels, nor in database entries. With what am I accessing nil object here?

Comment: Nobody can help you with the specifics. The only answer is "get a stack trace and work out what's going on". Put madExcept in your process. You are wasting your time otherwise.

Comment: Call me crazy, but this thing is WEIRD. It works, and ONLY works if I set query to WHERE ID <> 74.
And it successfully updates all labels but label[74]. If I put there any other number than 74, it breaks. Wtf?

Comment: Why are you asking us? I mean really, only you can see your code. What do you expect us to say? Are we meant to somehow read your mind and be able to see your code.

Comment: Well, looks like it was some internal bug. several restarts of RAD studio self-solved the problem, and now the thing goes through.
Even MadExcept didn't show any useful information.
However, now works all ok.
Sorry for bothering you all.

Comment: I would consider Output.Led[Channel-1] suspect, if that is your array of labels. This gets called quite 'randomly' with FieldByName('ID').AsInteger as the first parameter. How is this array created/allocated? Put an Assert(Output.Led[Channel-1] <> nil) as first statement in your SetDataValue routine. The fact that it suddenly stopped does not mean the issue has been correctly solved.

Comment: madExcept will give good diagnostics. You do need to get a better handle on this. Doesn't sound like you've really solved it. Bug is surely in your code.

Comment: The array is static, Output.Led: array [0..511] of TLabel; and is created with "for" loop, before the application executes, with OnCreate procedure, with .Left and .Top set according to the screen resolution, Channel-1 is there because in database I have IDs 1 to 512, so this should be correct. I don't know what u mean with "randomly" though; I call all of the 512 entries in database, and send them to static array with exact same number of objects. Why would it be a good thing to check if the label even exists..?
I don't know about it, but the fact is that it worked with no code changes at all

Comment: @JanDoggen - that "Why" question there was because I'm curious, why is this necessary when there should be 100% correct numbers in code, not like "Why would I do that if it works fine"... I'm learning, and am happy to find out new stuff! :)

Comment: Compile the program with `Use Debug DCUs` option and add some exception stack trace unroller/logger like JCL, MadExcept, EurekaLog or any of lots of other libraries mentioned on StackOverflow discussing exception stack tracel ogging or debug messaging for Delphi. There you have to see which function exactly reds from NIL and hopefully would develop more ideas hwo to narrow down your search

Comment: what about a query with `WHERE ID=74` instead ? what about filling `label[MaxLabelNo-74]` instead of `label[74]` ? in other words is it about reading a specific database row or is it about accessing a specific label ? I remember seeing some internal NIL dereference when opening a query with no rows returned, but that was not with ADO (either DBX or CDS or some custom text-file TDataSet implementation was used) and I do not remember details.

Comment: Happy new year guys.
No, it's not with ado, it's about Label component array, which gets created on run. Seems like it's completely disappeared, because now I can do either WHERE ID=74, or any other condition and it always works just as expected, without any errors. It's been updated with almost 22 other queries and a bunch of code and all works just fine. I'm still pretty sure it was some bug or something in the compiling itself, that disappeared after rebooting.
Good to know what all can cause that and how to debug with other tools, though. Thanks!